# Is there a way to get the Environment Admins of a Power Platform environment through Power Automate, Graph API, etc.?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-platform

I have reviewed the Power Platform Admin connector API and administrative Power Shell commands but have not found a way to get the assigned Environment Admins of a specific environment programmatically.

Comment: I guess you are aware that env admin and env maker roles are available only for env without database. If you have database to you env you only get env maker role and then you have systemadmin,System Customizer, basic user and so on role.
Could you please let us know if you are looking for with db or without db

Comment: @AnkUser: Thanks. Yes, aware of the different roles between env with DV and without DV instance. To clarify I have a large number of sections and we are trying to delegate control and responsibility to each section's assigned admin (Env Admin or Sys Admin - since they control the provisioning of DV). I might be able to just use a static PoC to simplify the process.

Have you used [List Environment Role Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerplatformforadmins/#list-environment-role-assignments)?

Comment: no I have not use list env role assignment. so I guess you have some sort of working solution for your req.

Comment: Testing. List Environment Role Assignments works for non-DV environments. I will add that as a partial answer. Guessing just use the Dataverse connector for DV environments? I will review Power Shell API as well.

Answer (score 0):

Environment Admins can be listed for Non-Dataverse environments using Power Automate and the Power Platform for Admins connector and List Environment Role Assignments Action.

[List Environment Role Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerplatformforadmins/#list-environment-role-assignments)

Pending Answer for Dataverse Environments